# Angular: manipulating event firing order - namely ng-blur & ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, events

I have two html elements: `<aleph>` and `<beth>`. The element `<aleph>` has a `ng-blur` attribute and the element `<beth>` has the `ng-click` attribute.

If I am in focus on elment `<aleph>` and click on `<beth>` it appears (according to experimentation) that the `ng-blur` will fire first and `ng-click` will fire next.

http://jsfiddle.net/UTn5y/70/

1. Will that always be the behavior?
2. Could I change that behavior without any effort?

Comment: No you cant do that. blur will fire first. what is your requirement to do this? if you can explain, i can help you.

Comment: So the answer to 1.  is yes? and 2. is no? Can you back it up with a source? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Will that always be the behavior?

Yes, the blur event will always be fired first

1. Could I change that behavior without any effort?

No you can not change the behavior. However, you can manage it by hand. You can use $timeout in your ng-blur callback, and check for a variable which can be manipulated by ng-click.

```
function ngClick () {
    $scope.clicked = true;
    // rest of your code
}

function ngBlur () {
    $scope.clicked = false;
    $timeout(function () { // will be executed after ngClick function in case of click
        if ($scope.clicked) {
            return;
        }

        // rest of your code
    })
}
```

Here is a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhfew91j/2/