# Why doesn't ng-click work when ng-blur used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have used `ng-click` on div and it works as expected, but when I have used `ng-blur` on some other input, the `ng-click` on the div stops working.

Working code [addItem(item) is being called on click]

```
 <div ng-controller="TestController">
  <input type="text" ng-focus="show=true">
  <div ng-show="show" class="choosecont">
    Choose from selected
    <div ng-repeat="item in allItems" ng-click="addItem(item)" class="choose">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chosencont">
    Following are selected
    <div ng-repeat="item in selectedItems" class="chosen">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Broken code [addItem(item) not being called]

```
 <div ng-controller="TestController">
  <input type="text" ng-focus="show=true" ng-blur="show=false">
  <div ng-show="show" class="choosecont">
    Choose from selected
    <div ng-repeat="item in allItems" ng-click="addItem(item)" class="choose">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chosencont">
    Following are selected
    <div ng-repeat="item in selectedItems" class="chosen">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related JS code

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.allItems = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  $scope.selectedItems = [];
  $scope.addItem = function(item) {
    if ($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item) == -1)
      $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
  }
}
]);
```

Here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/eI5dvczO2E1Cp1SBPgQx?p=preview
Click on input which will bring dropdown. Clicking on dropdown adds item to selected list in one case but not in other case.

I have tried to debug. scope is set correctly and it was accessible.

Comment: Basically your ng-blur executes before your ng-click. Check this SO answer, hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304260/angular-manipulating-event-firing-order-namely-ng-blur-ng-click

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `click` event fires after `blur`, so the list is being hidden before you are able to click it.  The [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event) is to use `mousedown` event instead of `click`:

`ng-mousedown="addItem(item)"`

Here is an update to your plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/sPGIb1afCayS1UiP73Q0?p=preview

Comment: Could you explain in your answer why the `mousedown` event is working and not the `click` ?

Comment: Check out the answer I linked to: "The mousedown and blur events occur one after another when you press the mouse button, but click only occurs when you release it."

Comment: After ~5 years, you are the hero even I use Angular 8.